# Save a value to NSUserDefaults when local notification is sent

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to run `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] saveObject:foo forKey:@"bar"];` as soon as my local notification is sent, without the need for the user to open the app. I understand that the app must be suspended for this to work, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it happen. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there's a reliable way to do that unless user opens app.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the date when the local notification will fire then you can calculate on next app open if this notification fired or not.